# git commit -v: how to hide not staged file list in verbose commit message?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a couple of unruly configuration repos, where keeping worktree clean is difficult due to falling behind on properly recording needed updates. That means a ton of files with unstaged changes.

This messes up `git commit -v` output, because the diff that I actually want to see while writing the commit message is all the way at the bottom.

Stashing before committing is not an option, because live apps may be watching configuration files and may get confused when they flip between states.

How do get rid of the "Changes not staged for commit" section?

Comment: You could just stash the unstaged changes.

Comment: Not an option. There may be apps inotify-watching configuration file changes and they would get confused.

Comment: Maybe\* it would be useful to include these constraints **in the question**? *(\* definitely)*

Comment: If there's no easy way to get the output you want, you might look into writing [a `prepare-commit-msg` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup, didn't think about that one. Edited.

Comment: Kind of begs the question: why do you have live apps watching your development repo? That seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @jonrsharpe note the "configuration repo" in the problem description. It's not a software development scenario, but keeping track of a server's `/etc` with a best available effort type of approach. I'm not enjoying the live watching either, but `NetworkManager` used to do that back in the day for just one example, so I learned not to rely on stashing. Not happy about it, but out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a temporary problem, I offer a temporary solution.

`git commit` in one window, `git diff --staged` in another.

(I say "temporary", but this is my normal workflow. I find working with `git diff` more useful than scrolling around in the editor between looking at the diff and editing the commit message. I use `git commit -v` as well, but only for verification that I'm committing basically the right thing.)

---

Alternatively, add sufficient lines to `.git/info/exclude` (not `.gitignore`) to suppress the bulk of the unstaged changes that you're not currently working on.  I suggest `.git/info/exclude` to avoid accidentally committing it.  As you work through the backlog, remove bunches of ignore lines to give yourself new chunks to work on.

Comment: Sure, `vim` horizontal split window is the way to go for now... Looking to optimize that out of the workflow.

Comment: Your workflow should not include so many unstaged files that they obscure your diff. I assume this is a temporary situation and you're working to fix it. So, putting in a bunch of work to optimize it seems like a waste of time. Instead, I suggest you make it work well enough while you fix the current mess.

Comment: I'm aware of the problem. Unfortunately, there are significantly more profitable activities that will take preference to cleaning this up properly, for a significant enough while, to make posting this question a reasonable bet.